# quiver matplotlib vector field 3d plot error: "too many values to unpack"

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

the following code doesnt work and gives me the error: "too many values to unpack". I got the code to try it directly from following website: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/quiver3d.html, so I dont know whats wrong. apparently all my libaries are properly installed, since I dont get any error.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Make the grid
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.2),
                      np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.2),
                      np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.8))

# Make the direction data for the arrows
u = np.sin(np.pi * x) * np.cos(np.pi * y) * np.cos(np.pi * z)
v = -np.cos(np.pi * x) * np.sin(np.pi * y) * np.cos(np.pi * z)
w = (np.sqrt(2.0 / 3.0) * np.cos(np.pi * x) * np.cos(np.pi * y) *
     np.sin(np.pi * z))

ax.quiver(x, y, z, u, v, w, length=0.1, normalize=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: A copy-n-paste of your code runs fine.  You need to show the complete traceback so we have some idea where the problem is occurring.

Comment: excuse me, here is the traceback:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Peter\OneDrive\Masterstudium\Photonik\Aufgabe 1\1.4.py", line 20, in <module>
    np.sin(np.pi * z)), length=0.1, normalize=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 6836, in quiver
    q = mquiver.Quiver(self, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\quiver.py", line 394, in __init__
    X, Y, U, V, C = _parse_args(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\quiver.py", line 356, in _parse_args
    nr, nc = U.shape
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: Better to put the traceback in the original question with clearer formatting.  Anyways you are using Py27, I only have `numpy` on Py3.  It's possible that the example was written and tested with PY3, and didn't take into account differences.

Comment: The example runs fine also with python 2.7. But in addition to showing the complete traceback within the question, can you also please state which matplotlib version you are using?